# How to add onclick to SVG and render new EJS template

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am seeking to render an EJS template when the user clicks on an SVG.

At the moment I understand when there is a form you assign a method of post and an action to the form. I am wondering if you can do the same with an SVG?

Here is my svg code with 'onclick' and a function within:

```
const svg = '<svg onclick="generate()" method="post" 
action="/new" 
    class="picto" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 
    123.4 145.4" enable-background="new 0 0 123.4 145.4" 
    xml:space="preserve">';
```

Here is my JS code:

```
app.post('/new',function (req, res) {
        res.render("new.ejs")
    });
```